# How to implement XRay in NodeJS with ECS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I have a cluster created in AWS ECS with two services:

1. my server with 20 tasks (node with express)
2. xray with 2 tasks (same region than my server)

Both are running well together, they have the same networking mode ("default"), and I did some pings from the server instance to xray instance and it's ok. I tried just the ping because telnet/curl/nc are not enabled. XRay is on port 2000 UDP.

In my app.js I have the initial setup:

import AWSXRay from 'aws-xray-sdk';
AWSXRay.setDaemonAddress('10.10.10.1:2000'); //It's an example, I'm hitting one of the instances (i took the private ip of one of them, because I have two)
app.use(AWSXRay.express.openSegment('MyApp')); //before declaring routes
app.use(AWSXRay.express.closeSegment()); //after declaring routes

I hit some endpoints but I can't see any trace or data in aws xray, maybe I need to setup something extra in AWS ?
I'm getting those legends on xray:
No services
Try adjusting the time range
0 traces retrieved

The xray service is running on port 2000, apparently is ok, the image is public.ecr.aws/xray/aws-xray-daemon:latest , both services (my server and xray) have the same task execution role with the following policies:
"xray:PutTraceSegments",
"xray:PutTelemetryRecords",
"xray:GetSamplingRules",
"xray:GetSamplingTargets",
"xray:GetSamplingStatisticSummaries"
)

Im totally stucked with this

I applied everything that aws-xray get started says and it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon.html#xray-daemon-logging
   Change xray daemon log to `dev`, if there is no logs indicate segment received ,the problem would be in application end or UDP network.
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-configuration.html#xray-sdk-nodejs-configuration-logging
   Then change xray js sdk log level, see if the segment is generated and flushed to daemon.